# Achieve this effect: Glowing outline of a photograph

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects

There's an image effect I want to recreate. Heres the image (SLIGHTLY NSFW): [Image](http://praxisprint.de/Blog/Bilder/NeueProdukte/roterotik.jpg)

I can roughly recreate the effect, but I don't like it as much. My steps are:

**The Original**

[image: Hot air baloon]

**Step 1: Duplicate, desaturate, smart blur (edges only), blend mode**

[image: Outlines]

**Step 2: Fiddle with curves**

And in the end, I can play around with colors. Unfortunately, I seem to have saved the picture incorrectly, however, not too much changes anyway.

**Done**

So now I'm reasonably happy with it, but...

**Problems**

...but the edges are still very thin and I cant find a very good way to make them stronger. Also, in the image I want to recreate, there is a strong white glow on thicker lines - not so in my version. Here, the color is just 'shining trough'.

**Any ideas on how to improve this?**

Thank you very much for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the entire image you're trying to copy is done with the Glowing Edges filter and then adjusting the Hue/Saturation.

I believe in new versions of Photoshop its been moved to the Filter Gallery. So get to it by Filter → Filter Gallery → Stylize → Glowing Edges

Comment: Well, that was massively wasted effort on my part. Thanks.